# Largest Series Product

Tags: c#

> Given a string of digits, calculate the largest product for a contiguous substring of digits of length n.  For example, for the input '1027839564', the largest product for a series of 3 digits is 270 (9 * 5 * 6), and the largest product for a series of 5 digits is 7560 (7 * 8 * 3 * 9 * 5).  Note that these series are only required to occupy adjacent positions in the input; the digits need not be numerically consecutive.  For the input '73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934', the largest product for a series of 6 digits is 23520.>

I am trying to complete a code challenge from [exercism.io](https://exercism.io/my/solutions/e3a41c92b2f94a42833f8e33f741632c)  That is the description given.  I am on my second refactor yet I am still failing on two test cases.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public static class LargestSeriesProduct
{
    /* Function to get product of digits */
    static int getProduct(int n)
    {
        int product = 1;

        while (n != 0)
        {
            product = product * (n % 10);
            n = n / 10;
        }

        return product;
    }

    static long getAnswer(string d, int s)
    {
        List<string> listString = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < d.Length - s + 1; ++i)
            listString.Add(d.Substring(i, s));

        List<int> listInt = listString.ConvertAll(int.Parse);

        return getProduct(listInt.Max());
    }

    public static long GetLargestProduct(string digits, int span)
    {
        if (span > digits.Length)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Rejects_span_longer_than_string_length");
        }

        else if (span == 0 || digits.Length == 0)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        else if (span == 1 && digits.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Rejects_empty_string_and_nonzero_span");
        }

        else if (span < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Rejects_negative_span");
        }

        else if (!digits.All(char.IsDigit))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Rejects_invalid_character_in_digits");
        }

        else if (digits.All(c => c == '0'))
        {
            return 0;
        }

        else
        {
            return getAnswer(digits, span);
        }
    }
}






/*
public static class LargestSeriesProduct
{
    public static long GetLargestProduct(string digits, int span)
    {
        try
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(0, digits.Length - span + 1).
            Select(i => digits.Substring(i, span)).
            Select(x => x.Aggregate(1, (a, b) => a * Convert.ToInt32(b.ToString()))).
            Max();
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
    }
}
*/
```

The code that is commented out is the most popular answer.  However, that is not my answer an I am trying to figure this out on my own.  I walked through the code one test at a time.  I am stuck on two test cases.  The following two cases have skip enabled on the test

```
// This file was auto-generated based on version 1.2.0 of the canonical data.

using System;
using Xunit;

public class LargestSeriesProductTest
{
    [Fact]
    public void Finds_the_largest_product_if_span_equals_length() => Assert.Equal(18, LargestSeriesProduct.GetLargestProduct("29", 2));

    [Fact]
    public void Can_find_the_largest_product_of_2_with_numbers_in_order() => Assert.Equal(72, LargestSeriesProduct.GetLargestProduct("0123456789", 2));

    [Fact(Skip = "specific reason")]
    public void Can_find_the_largest_product_of_2() => Assert.Equal(48, LargestSeriesProduct.GetLargestProduct("576802143", 2));

    [Fact]
    public void Can_find_the_largest_product_of_3_with_numbers_in_order() => Assert.Equal(504, LargestSeriesProduct.GetLargestProduct("0123456789", 3));

    [Fact]
    public void Can_find_the_largest_product_of_3() => Assert.Equal(270, LargestSeriesProduct.GetLargestProduct("1027839564", 3));

    [Fact]
    public void Can_find_the_largest_product_of_5_with_numbers_in_order() => Assert.Equal(15120, LargestSeriesProduct.GetLargestProduct("0123456789", 5));

    [Fact(Skip = "specific reason")]
    public void Can_get_the_largest_product_of_a_big_number() => Assert.Equal(23520, LargestSeriesProduct.GetLargestProduct("73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934", 6));

    [Fact]
    public void Reports_zero_if_the_only_digits_are_zero() => Assert.Equal(0, LargestSeriesProduct.GetLargestProduct("0000", 2));

    [Fact]
    public void Reports_zero_if_all_spans_include_zero() => Assert.Equal(0, LargestSeriesProduct.GetLargestProduct("99099", 3));

    [Fact]
    public void Rejects_span_longer_than_string_length() => Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() => LargestSeriesProduct.GetLargestProduct("123", 4));

    [Fact]
    public void Reports_1_for_empty_string_and_empty_product_0_span_() => Assert.Equal(1, LargestSeriesProduct.GetLargestProduct("", 0));

    [Fact]
    public void Reports_1_for_nonempty_string_and_empty_product_0_span_() => Assert.Equal(1, LargestSeriesProduct.GetLargestProduct("123", 0));

    [Fact]
    public void Rejects_empty_string_and_nonzero_span() => Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() => LargestSeriesProduct.GetLargestProduct("", 1));

    [Fact]
    public void Rejects_invalid_character_in_digits() => Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() => LargestSeriesProduct.GetLargestProduct("1234a5", 2));

    [Fact]
    public void Rejects_negative_span() => Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() => LargestSeriesProduct.GetLargestProduct("12345", -1));
}
```

I have tried regex to remove the 0's, but that causes other passing test to fail.  I have tried changing 0's to 1's, but that creates a different product.  The best clue I can give to pass all these test are in the commented out code below my own.  I am trying to work with what I got, complete it, and then go and refactor it into something less verbose with the knowledge I have with C#.  I am new to C#.

Any help with passing those two test without failing the other test I have passed is much appreciated.

Comment: The logic behind your call in `getAnswer` of `getProduct(listInt.Max());` is incorrect, it will pass the largest integer in your list to that method. You probably want `listInt.Max(getProduct)`

Comment: That fails this test here

`public void Reports_zero_if_all_spans_include_zero() => Assert.Equal(0, LargestSeriesProduct.GetLargestProduct("99099", 3));`

Comment: It does however pass the other two test that I was previously failing.

Comment: Yes, you have a problem due to converting strings like `099` to integers not keeping the leading 0 for your product calculation.

Comment: Close, What it is failing on is the substring 990.  9 * 9 * 0 = 0.  The test wants 0.

Comment: 990 is > 099.  So it wants to do 9 * 9 * 0 = 0.  But instead its reporting 81.

Comment: It's the second part of that test, the last triplet, `099`, that's returning a non-zero answer. It parses to 99. Your product calculates it to 81. I assume that's the result you're getting.

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: The most popular answer is *flawed* for large spans and results, be different and use `BigInteger` for the win, `n.Aggregate(new BigInteger(1), (current, t) => current * (t - '0'))`

Comment: The most popular answer passes against this number **73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934**.

As for your suggestion I am unsure where you are suggesting to call it?

Comment: that's not a number its a string, and its the span that will determine the overflow

Comment: Your suggestion is still unclear to me as in its placement in the code itself.
`n.Aggregate(new BigInteger(1), (current, t) => current * (t - '0'))`

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Aa9tJq

Comment: Thank you Michael Randall for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what Michael Randall was saying now.  This was the code suggested in that link.  It passes all test.  I'm just going to accept this and disregard my code as being unacceptable to refactor.  This is more concise and readable as well.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Numerics;

public static class LargestSeriesProduct
{
    static BigInteger getAnswer(string d, int s) => Enumerable.Range(0, d.Length - s + 1)
        .Select(i => d.Substring(i, s))
        .Select(n => n.Aggregate(new BigInteger(1), (current, t) => current * (t - '0')))
        .OrderByDescending(x => x)
        .First();

    public static long GetLargestProduct(string digits, int span)
    {
        if (span > digits.Length)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Rejects_span_longer_than_string_length");
        }

        else if (span == 0 || digits.Length == 0)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        else if (span == 1 && digits.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Rejects_empty_string_and_nonzero_span");
        }

        else if (span < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Rejects_negative_span");
        }

        else if (!digits.All(char.IsDigit))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Rejects_invalid_character_in_digits");
        }

        else if (digits.All(c => c == '0'))
        {
            return 0;
        }

        else
        {
            return (int)getAnswer(digits, span);
        }
    }
}
```